# jquery-ui icons

Tags: jquery-ui

I understand that if I use this:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("jqueryui", "1");
</script>
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span>
```

Then an arrow appears.
I don't understand how to wrap the arrow with this:

```
ui-state-default ui-corner-all
```

because themeroller is using list items, and I'm using table head cells.
I don't want to use:

```
<th class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
```

because that highlights the entire cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh!  It looks like I can just use:

```
<span class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span>
```